# Jinja iterate on dictionary

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the following dictionary

```
{
  2: {'name': 'e', 'abilities': [] }, 
  3: {'name': 'xyx', 'abilities': []}, 
  1: {'name': 'user', 'abilities': ['can_add', 'can_delete']}
}
```

How can I iterate on it in `jinja2` using `flask`?

I need to get id,name,abilities.

Comment: Based on your tagging, I assume you want to iterate through it in Jinja Templates?

Comment: Yes it should be jijna2 template

Comment: Nope beacuse every time i do it i get
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: Please, post your code.